# How can I create a tar file from a list of files in another tar file?

Tags: tar

I have a process that creates a tar file with copies of files that need to be updated.

I want to backup existing files before overwriting with the new files.

I've tried

```
tar cf backup.tar -T `tar tf updated.tar`
```

Which didn't work.  If I pipe the output from tar tf to a file, then use that as the -T param it works:

```
tar tf updated.tar > list; tar cf backup.tar -T list
```

But it seems to me that I should be able to accomplish this in one command.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify *stdin* as input file, e.g.:

tar tf updated.tar | tar cf backup.tar -T -

Answer (score 1):

The -T option is specifically looking for a file, not a list. Your first attempt passes a list to -T, which is probably why it doesn't work. I would try something like:

```
tar tf updated.tar | xargs tar cf backup.tar
```

Comment: This may fail in some rare cases. The maximum number of allowed command line arguments is restricted. See `getconf ARG_MAX`.

Comment: Good point... so H. Dirk Schmitt's answer is probably better.

Comment: @H.-DirkSchmitt: It should be noted that `xargs` normally takes care of this by splitting the command in multiple invocations. (It just doesn't work as expected here since a second `tar c` overwrites the first output.)

Answer (score -1):

I use this commande:

```
tar cf backup.tar `tar tf updated.tar`
```